# Excel T.TEST regular formula returns different result than array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, array-formulas

As can be seen, the result differs, although the cells provided as input for calculation are same.

[image: T.TEST non-array formula vs. array formula]

```
=T.TEST(B1:B4,B5:B8,2,2)
{=T.TEST(IF($A$1:$A$8="a",B$1:B$8,""),IF($A$1:$A$8="b",B$1:B$8,""),2,2)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bug in array formula, because blank cells are treated differently:

- if `T.TEST` is a non-array formula, blank cells are omitted;
- if `T.TEST` is inside an array formula, then it does not omit them, but instead treats blank cells as zeros.

[image: T.TEST results with and without zeros]

If array formula is required, one would need to explicitly check for blank cells, which can be done like this:

[image: working T.TEST array formula]

```
{=T.TEST(IF(($A$1:$A$8="a")*(B$1:B$8<>""),B$1:B$8,""),IF(($A$1:$A$8="b")*(B$1:B$8<>""),B$1:B$8,""),2,2)}
```

In Excel array formulas `AND` cannot be used, so instead of `AND($A$1:$A$8="a",B$1:B$8<>"")` we write `($A$1:$A$8="a")*(B$1:B$8<>"")`.